# How to put an enum as dataSource for devextreme select box

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, devextreme

I want to fill the select box with enum values that are a property of a class
My HTML:

```
<div class="channel-visible">
        <div class="title">Sichtberagt</div>
        <dx-select-box
        [(value)]="newChannel.visibility"
        [dataSource]="channelVisibility"
        >

        </dx-select-box>
    </div>
```

My component:

```
channelVisibility = EChannelVisibility;
newChannel = new Channel();
```

Enum type EChannelVisibility is a property of the class Channel.
If I try to implement it in HTML above I get this error:
[image: Error when assigning a data Source to a devextreme select box]

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to construct a string array from your enum.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

enum EChannelVisiblity {
  Up = 'UP',
  Down = 'DOWN',
  Left = 'LEFT',
  Right = 'RIGHT'
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  visibility!: any;
  channelVisibility!: any;

  constructor() {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i in EChannelVisiblity) {
      arr.push(i.toString());
    }

    this.channelVisibility = arr;
  }
}
```